# Bluetoothle format for sending data

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

Currently I am working on my app which is going to run some code after receiving a specific type of data

So when I push on button, my arduino is going to send the following:
for button 1

```
  ble_write(0x0A);
  ble_write(0x01);
  ble_write(0x00);
```

for button 2:
    ble_write(0x0A);
    ble_write(0x02);
    ble_write(0x00);

The data is received by my phone but the problem is, it would only put out the code 1 toast and not code 2 when i press button 2. here is the code for my app.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
        if (data[i] == 0x0A) {
            if (data[i + 1] == 0x01)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CODE 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (data[i] == 0x02) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CODE 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

I feel like because of the for loop it will just take one byte and always see it as code 1.

The code is based on: https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android/blob/master/Examples/Android%20Studio%20Examples/SimpleControls/src/com/redbear/simplecontrols/SimpleControls.java

I am kinda stuck dealing with the problem, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to change the received data (byte[]) to a string format via a standard character set. (UTF_8)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the curly braces ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
        if (data[i] == 0x0A) {
            if (data[i + 1] == 0x01) { // <- added {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CODE 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (data[i + 1] == 0x02) { // added '+ 1'
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CODE 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } //<- added }
}
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, but thanks for the comment. As it stands, when the data is received, the code will only put out the toast "Code 1". I think this is because of the for loop, but I tried to remove the for loop but it seems that I need to use this loop to be able to get access to the data.  I tried to do a method like so If (data = 0x02) but that didn't do anything at all.

Comment: Try and print out the byte array as a hexString to see what you actually receive when pressing each of the buttons. Use the method here: http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/606209